# How rebuild TFS workspace from the command line?

Tags: command-line, tfs, tf-cli

I need to rebuild my local workspace on my workstation in order to remove a number of conflicting changes that prevent me from making further changes.

I'm getting the following error and need to resolve it so that I can continue with my work.

> Conflict "uc_example.ascx.cs" - Unable to perform the get operation Because you have any available conflicting edit

I prefer to do this from the command line.

Comment: Why do you need to do that?

Comment: I just want to test a possible solution to the following error: Conflict "uc_example.ascx.cs" - Unable to perform the get operation Because you have any available conflicting edit

Comment: I think the workspace be soiled, have to remove it, create it and map it

Comment: Can you describe the things you ran, what the exact output is and what the current pending changes on the `uc_example.ascx.cs` are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Try to resolve the issue first

To see what changes there are pending on the file in question you can run:

```
tf status $/path/to/your/uc_example.ascx.cs /format:detailed 
         /collection:http://yourserver:8080/tfs/YourCollection /user:*
```

Optionally include a workspace using teh `/workspace:name` parameter.

To undo the pending changes on your file (make sure you have a backup of the to be content):

```
tf undo $/path/to/your/uc_example.ascx.cs
         /collection:http://yourserver:8080/tfs/YourCollection
```

Optionally add the workspace where you need to undo the change (you may need to have Undo other people's changes permissions).

```
tf undo $/path/to/your/uc_example.ascx.cs 
         /workspace:TheWorkspaceWithEditYouWantGone;OwnerOfSaidWorkspace
         /collection:http://yourserver:8080/tfs/YourCollection
```

To see what changes there are pending on the file in question you can run:

```
tf status $/path/to/your/uc_example.ascx.cs /format:detailed 
         /collection:http://yourserver:8080/tfs/YourCollection
```

If there is a pending `delete` you cannot try to check in a pending `edit`. Or if there is a pending `merge` you cannot do a `delete`. This may happen when you delete a file (which pends a `delete`), then create a new file with the same name (which will try to pend an `add`, and fails). You will either need to check in your delete first, or undo your delete and then overwrite the file. You can't `delete` and `add` in the same checkin.

### If that fails, blow away the workspace

If that doesn't help you can remove the workspace, create a new one, get the latest sources, reapply your changes and try to check them in.

> WARNING THIS WILL BLOW AWAY ALL PENDING CHANGES ON THE WORKSPACE
>   MAKE SURE YOU HAVE A BACKUP BEFORE PROCEEDING!

```
tf undo /workspace:YourWorkspaceName /recursive /noprompt
         /collection:http://yourserver:8080/tfs/YourCollection

tf workspace /delete /collection:http://yourserver:8080/tfs/YourCollection 
         /workspace:YourWorkspaceName

tf workspace /new /noprompt /collection:http://yourserver:8080/tfs/YourCollection 
        /location:local YourWorkspaceName

tf workfold /map $/Server/Folder d:\Your\Local\Path /workspace:YourWorkspaceName
        /collection:http://yourserver:8080/tfs/YourCollection
```

> WARNING BELOW LINE WILL GET AND FORCE ALL FILES TO THE LATEST VERSION

```
tf get d:\Your\Local\Path /recursive /version:T /force /overwrite
```

But if the item has a conflicting change on another person's workspace, it won't help you to blow away your workspace.